# $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} {1\over\sqrt{1+t^3}}dt$, $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f\ni \lambda g''=g^2,\lambda=?$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} {1\over\sqrt{1+t^3}}dt$, $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f\ni \lambda g''=g^2$ we need to find $\lambda$

my try:

$f(g(x))=x\Rightarrow \int_{0}^{g(x)} {1\over\sqrt{1+t^3}}dt=x\Rightarrow f'(g(x))g'(x)={1\over\sqrt{1+[g(x)]^3}}=1$

am I going into the right path?

Answer (score 0):

You expression is wrong, what you really have is :

$$f'(g(x))g'(x) = \frac{g'(x)}{\sqrt{1+g(x)^3}} = 1$$